# Parse Server login return a user, but req.user is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-server

I am trying to set up a simple authentification system with Parse Server:

app.js

```
...

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.ejs');
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST /login\t' + util.inspect(req.body));
    driver.login(req, (err, user) => {
        //Here, user is defined
        if(err) {
            res.redirect('/login');
        } else {
            res.redirect('/user');
        }
    });
});

...
```

driver.js:

```
...

function login(req, callback) {
    var username = req.body.username,
        password = req.body.password;
    Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
        success: (user) => {
            callback();
        },
        error: (user, error) => {
            callback(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}

function isLoggedIn(req, callback) {
    console.log('isLoggedIn?');
    console.log(util.inspect(req.user)); //undefined
    if(req.user) {
        callback();
    } else {
        callback('Not logged in');
    }
}

...
```

When I access `/login`, I can login just fine, and get redirected to `/user` without any error, but on `/user`, which use `isLoggedIn` as a middleware, `req.user` is undefined.

I have seen others with the same problem when searching, but the post where either old (<2015), using another part of the JSSDK (react/browser), or just didn t get any answer.

I know I could use session, and recreate the user each time based on that, but it feels really hackish, is it really the supported way?

Comment: DrakaSAN - how you want to support session and storage data in session? As @sookool99 mentions - you need one more abstraction layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two routes to go, either have a REST-full server, which means users are not persistent between route calls, STATE-full and use sessions.

Luckily there is a really good nodejs authentication middleware already build that will handle all this session managment. This is called passportJS. Documentation can be found here: http://passportjs.org/docs

You can not only have authentication through local logins, but have support for authentication with google, facebook, github and many more. This is done through what are called Strategies. You use google-strategy for having google oauth, facebook-stradegy for facebook oauth, etc.

What you would be looking for is a local-strategy, which is called this because you want to authenticate with local user credentials. This strategy can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local

you will need both passport and passport local and to install simply run

```
npm install passport passport-local
```

From there, just go through the documentation I have linked above for how to set everything up.

Comment: I know about passport, problem is that after the authentification, I want to make use of Parse, so passport is not a real solution.

Comment: @DrakaSAN how did you solve this finally ? Did you use Passeport as suggested or is there a better practice ? I'm in the exact same situation.

Comment: @blablabla: Posted as a answer :)

Answer (score 2):

To develop my answer to blablabla comment, who asked what I ended up using.

In my case, I was develloping a REST API, and the session data wasn't expected to change once connected.

So what I did is delegate the session to the client, and go full stateless, by using [JWT](https://jwt.io/).

When the client is authentified, I encrypt his session data in a Json Web Token, and send him. When he try to access a protected page, he send me the JWT, which I can decrypt, and recreate `req.user` based on the information within.

My middleware look like this:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    //If there is a token
    if(req.headers != null && req.headers.token != null) {
        //Verify it and extract the user's data
        verify(req.headers.token, (err, user) => {
            if(err != null) {
                res.status(401);
                res.json({error: err});
            } else {
                //Recreate req.user
                req.user = user;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(401);
        res.json({error: 'No token'});
    }
}

function verify(token, callback) {
    //Verify the token
    jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, (error, user) => {
        if(error != null) {
            callback(error);
        } else {
            Separately check if logged into Parse
            parse.isLoggedIn(user, (error, loggedIn) => {
                if(error != null) {
                    callback(error);
                } else if(!loggedIn) {
                    callback('Not logged in the Parse');
                } else {
                    callback(null, user);
                }
            });             
        }
    });
}
```